# Linq to Crm (2011) Trouble searching by username for systemuser

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a win app that is using linq to crm to query a system user by username 
in Crm 2011(IFD). I have the following code snippet which shows what I am trying 
to accomplish. The method executes without error, however no records are found.
The username appears as "domain\testuser" om CRM.

```
 public static SystemUser LookUpSystemUser()
    {
        var username= "domain\\testuser");

        var list = (from c in Context.CreateQuery<SystemUser>()
                    where c.DomainName.Equals(username)
                    select c).ToList();

        return list.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: If you remove the `where` do you get any results?

Comment: Another option would be to find the user you'd like to find in CRM, and retrieve the user by it's Guid, and inspect it's domain name to see why it's not being found.

Comment: is your case correct?  You might try c.DomainName.Equals(username, stringcomparison.ignorecase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreating the application seemed to fix the problem. There are still no code differences, so still unsure what happened.

Comment: Did you change your DB collation by any chance? Different collation might result in change of case sensitivity, giving you different results.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't an answer to your question, and in your particular instance it really won't matter due to there only being one SystemUser per DomainName, but it is a best practice.

When calling `ToList()` on your LINQ statement, it will return all entities from the SQL database that match the query.  Then calling `FirstOrDefault()` will return the first, client side.

Instead of calling `ToList()` when only interested in one, call `FirstOrDefault()`.  This will actually result in `Top 1` added to the select query.  This will result in less resources being consumed on the SQL server, CRM Webserver, and data being transfered between the SQL server, the CRM Webserver, and the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this method (or a canonical equivalent of it) and see if you get anything at all. If so, you can then tighten up the condition in *Select* statement.

```csharp
public static SystemUser LookUpSystemUser()
{
  return Context.CreateQuery<SystemUser>()
    .Select(element => true)
    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Remember that *default(SystemUser)* will produce *null*.

*Not at the computer, haven't tested it.*